# Pandas dataframe "Must have equal len keys and values..." error seems to activate based on dataframe length

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have run across an unexplainable problem with Pandas regarding inserting a numpy array into the cell of a Dataframe.  I am aware of the standard fixes for this error, but this case seems to be a little stranger.

I load a .csv file into a dataframe, collapse the last 1000 rows into a numpy array and place them back into a cell in a new dataframe.

The header format of the original file is essentially:

`["TIMESTAMP", "Header0", ... , "Header10", "Waveform (1)", ... , "Waveform (1001)"]`

```py
# Load in dataframe from csv file, skipping some extra headers
input_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=1, skiprows=[2, 3], index_col='TIMESTAMP', parse_dates=True)

# Header columns that are not part of the waveform
header_columns = ["Header0", "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", 
                    "Header4", "Header5", "Header6", "Header7",
                    "Header8", "Header9", "Header10"]
    
# Create a version of the input df that is only the Waveform columns, dropping the last one
waveform_df = input_df.drop(columns=header_columns).iloc[:, :-1]

# Create a version of the input df that is only the Header columns
header_df = input_df[indexing_columns]

# Create an output df that is a copy of the header df with a column added for storing the compressed waveforms
output_df = header_df.copy()
output_df['Waveform'] = None

# for every row in the waveform dict (which will be the same len as output_df)
for index, row in waveform_df.iterrows():
    # create a numpy array from all the waveform columns of that row
    waveform_array = waveform_df.loc[index].to_numpy()
    # save the numpy array in the 'Waveform' column of the current row by index
    output_df.at[index, 'Waveform'] = waveform_array

# return the compressed df
return output_df
```

This code actually works perfectly fine most of the time.  The file I originally tested it on worked fine, and had 30 or so rows in it.  However, when I attempted to run the same code on a different file with the same header formats which was about 1200 rows, it gave the error:

`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

for the line:

`output_df.at[index, 'Waveform'] = waveform_array`

I compared the two incessantly and discovered that the only real difference between the two is the length, and in fact, if I crop the longer dataframe to a similar length to the shorter one, the error disappears. (Specifically, it works so long as I crop the dataframe to less than 250 rows)

I'd really like to be able to do this without cropping the dataframe and rebuilding it, so I was wondering if anyone had an insight into why this error was occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: While the question is interesting, and unfortunately I cannot help with this limit, I'm not sure keeping np.arrays as cells in the dataframe is the best idea. Why don't you keep those in a list, and just store indices in your dataframe?
Or convert the whole thing to a np.matrix altogether.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski It is my instinct as well that keeping np.array's in the cells of a dataframe is bad practice, but I'm not entirely sure why.  I suppose it's an instinct carried over from working with Relational Databases.  The other methods are certainly a possibility, but this way seemed the most straightforward, given the need for easy Timestamp indexing.  I will definitely look into keeping the indices of a matrix in the dataframe; that seems like the best solution.

I still am miffed about the error though, I hate it when code doesn't work and I don't know why...

Comment: How sure are you that the index is unique? Cause this is the problem I'd expect you to see if the index isn't unique.

Comment: The full error traceback often helps.  Being able to reproduce the error is also nice, but that seems to depend on access to large csv files.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that the index is unique.  Unfortunately due to the nature of my job, a full traceback is not available.  However, I did some further testing and did find that no matter where in the dataframe I select from, as long as the section is less than 250 rows, no error occurs.  Otherwise, it does.  It must be some issue behind the scenes to do with large datasets.

Comment: Does it still happen if you replace your loop with `output_df.loc[index, 'Waveform'] = row.values`?